# Java: add two values of the same type where both are subclasses of java.lang.Number

Tags: java

I want to have a constructor like the following.

```
public Attribute(String attrName, Number attrValue){
    this.name = attrName;
    this.value = attrValue;
}
```

In this I would like to have a method called incrementValue(Number n) which will add n to value. I know you cannot add two Number objects together due to the possible issues with casting. However, if I use a check to guarantee value and n are the same type is it possible to add these together? Or perhaps there is a better way to go about this.

Right now I am declaring instance variables of Integer and Double and assign the value to the correct type. I was wondering about expanding this to allow for any subclass of Number. Obviously I could write separate methods for each one but that seems like bad programming.

Is this possible in java? Am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: What the justification for using the abstract superclass `Number`. Are you using concrete subclasses further down in your heirarchy?

Comment: @Perception I wanted to allow for as many possible types as I could allow since this is for practice/fun and might want to expand on it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [convert all `Number`s to a single type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) (`double` is least-lossy):

```
class Attribute {

    private double value;

    public Attribute(String attrName, Number attrValue) {
        this.name = attrName;
        this.value = attrValue.doubleValue();
    }

}
```

But IMO you're better off just overloading the constructor; `Number` is really just not a terribly useful class in my experience (and [I don't seem to be the only one who thinks so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671787/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-number-class)).

```
class Attribute {

    public Attribute(String attrName, int attrValue) {
        this.name = attrName;
        this.value = attrValue;
    }

    public Attribute(String attrName, double attrValue) {
        this.name = attrName;
        this.value = attrValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have now. I was hoping to allow for BigInteger, BigDecimal, Byte, etc. After creating an incrementValue() method for each the code is a lot of copy paste.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, is there a good reason to include the other types? I was thinking this could possibly be stored in a database and thought I might need allow for all types.

Comment: To add `BigInteger` and `BigDouble`, you have to use [instance methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)). **You cannot use `+`.** I would rethink your design, and whether or not you really need to support every single possible numeric type.

Comment: I've written numerous applications which store numbers in a database and **not once have I ever needed to write anything like what you're trying to do.** Say, 95% of the time, all you need is `int` (or `long`) and `double`. And there is almost certainly no compelling reason to mix numeric types or write this as generically as you're trying to. So no, I cannot see a reason (unless you present one) that possibly storing a number in a database means you have to "allow all types." Yes, I am being curmudgeonly.

Comment: edit: This is actually very good to hear. I am doing this as practice that I might have wanted to expand later. Thank you for the info about databases.

Comment: I would also be very wary of using `Integer`/`Double` instead of `int`/`double`. Unless you really do want to allow `null` as a possible value, stick with the primitives wherever possible. Obviously, this excludes collections, but that's what autoboxing is for (when you don't mind the performance hit) and [Trove Collections](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) (when you do).

Comment: Well originally I was using the Object instead of the primitive since I was using multiple instance variables for the different types and wanted to allow the value 0 but still check which value was initialized. Clearly flawed thinking and I think I will take the approach you gave and consolidate to one type.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in Java.  The best you can do is to go through all the cases of `Number` you know about.

I could certainly write a `Number` subclass for which it was impossible, though it'd be a slightly nonsensical implementation.